# Auto scale on Amazon S3 based on transfer

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm waiting for Account confirmation in Amazon AWS, till then I can't experiment.

First of all, I found the docs about auto scaling in Amazon AWS, but all of them mention Amazon EC2, there is no info regarding S3. Is there such a thing for S3?

Second - is this possible to scale up in case of increased traffic? The docs mention CPU and RAM usage, nothing about traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to auto scale Amazon S3 buckets, this is on it's side.

What you have to do is to scale up the EC2 instance.

I suggest you to read [AUTOSCALING YOUR WEBSITE WITH AMAZON WEB SERVICES – PART 1](http://www.cardinalpath.com/autoscaling-your-website-with-amazon-web-services-part-1/) and [AUTO SCALING YOUR WEBSITE WITH AMAZON WEB SERVICES (AWS) – PART 2](http://www.cardinalpath.com/autoscaling-your-website-with-amazon-web-services-part-2/) where it is really well explained step by step.

Comment: Thank you! One question though - I want to serve static files only, like images. Therefore I shouldn't be interested in EC2 at all, right? Only S3, yes?

Comment: You can create a static website on S3, in this case you don't need an EC2.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a scalable service. There is nothing to be done on your side.

For instances, you would want to use elastic beanstalk. It allows autoscale on certain metrics like cpu utilization, network io etc. This is essentially to add more application servers when your load exceeds one of these thresholds.